# IOmeter v/s FIO on Windows VM

Tags: windows, testing, storage, benchmarking

I have a Windows VM which have disks on high performance storage. I have both **FIO**(http://bluestop.org/fio/) and **IOmeter**(http://www.iometer.org/) installed on it. I want to be able to saturate the disks to obtain max IOPs through FIO, but I see that FIO is not reaching the IOmeter IOPs level(FIO is showing around 100k IOPs lesser than IOmeter).

**IOmeter config:**

- 1 worker per disk (8 disks)
- 64 oio on each worker (iodepth)
- 4k random writes (workload)
- 4kb akigned IOs

**FIO config:**

```
[global]
rw=randread
rwmixread=100
blocksize=4096
blockalign=4096
ioengine=windowsaio
group_reporting=1
iodepth=64
description=fio 4KB random read 8disk
time_based=1
runtime=300
direct=1
numjobs=8   //Keeping it at 1 job per disk as in IOmeter gave even lower IOPs

[fio-job-01]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive1
[fio-job-02]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive2
[fio-job-03]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive3
[fio-job-04]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive4
[fio-job-05]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive5
[fio-job-06]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive6
[fio-job-07]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive7
[fio-job-08]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive8
```

Is there something that I can add in my FIO config to improve the IOPs?

Thanks.

Comment: (I think this would be better asked over on https://superuser.com/ ). `rwmixread=100` seems unnecessary when you aren't requesting a `rw` workload. Are you aware you're asking for 64 threads (you have 8 jobs - `fio-job-01` - `fio-job-08` and you've asked them to be duplicated 8 times via `numjobs=8`)?

Comment: Yes, rwmixread seems unnecessary, removed it. Thanks! Also, I'm aware i'm spawning 64 jobs. With 8 jobs I got relatively higher IOPs than for 1 job(not sure if this is the right way to go ahead). Now posted it on superuser too.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend deleting it here...

Comment: (NB: the repost @nidHi was referring to is  https://superuser.com/questions/1411056/iometer-v-s-fio-on-windows-vm )